# How do I index HTML files into Apache SOLR?

Tags: html, apache, solr, indexing, inverted-index

By default SOLR accepts XML files, I want to perform search on millions of crawled URLS (html).

Comment: When I google `How do I index HTML files into Apache SOLR?` I see some promising resources. Do they not work for you?

Comment: "By default SOLR accepts XML files" <- nope, this is incorrect.

Comment: The [UpdateRequestHandler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateRequestHandler) accepts XML and is available by default. What on earth do you mean? And what's with the attitude?

Answer (score 2):

Usually, the first step I would recommend rolling your own application using SolrJ or similar to handle the indexing, and not do it directly with the DataImportHandler.

Just write your application and have that output the contents of those web pages as a field in a SolrInputDocument. I recommend stripping the HTML in that application, because it gives you greater control. Besides, you probably want to get at some of the data inside that pag, such as `<title>`, and index it to a different field. An alternative is to use [HTMLStripTransformer](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#HTMLStripTransformer) on one of your fields to make sure it strips HTML out of anything that you send to that field.

How are you crawling all this data? If you're using something like [Apache Nutch](http://nutch.apache.org) it should already take care of most of this for you, allowing you to just plug in the connection details of your Solr server.

Comment: I agree, use Apache Nutch which has direct integration with Solr.

Answer (score 1):

Solr CEL can accept HTML and indexes them for full-text search: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler

```
curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/update/extract?literal.id=doc1&commit=true" -F "myfile=@tutorial.html"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can index downloaded html file with solr very well.

This is the fastest way that I did my indexing:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/solr/update/extract?stream.file=/home/index.html&literal.id=www.google.com
```

Here `stream.file` is the local path of your html file and `literal.id` is url from `index.html`.